# extract all the xtables in to the one .tex file from r

Tags: xetex, luatex, r

I  have two xtables in my R script and I would like to extract them the same .tex file then I can call them to my main.tex with \newcommand

```
print(xtable(head(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars1", label="tab:tbl1", scalebox="0.8"), file = 'tabl1.tex')
print(xtable(tail(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars2", label="tab:tbl2", scalebox="0.8"), file = 'tabl2.tex')
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include `tabl1.tex` you only have to use `\input{tabl1}` in the `main.tex`. But moreover, you do not need at all run a R script to export the table to two tex files and then include these files in a main file and run the latex compiler.

One file and one (apparent) run is  enough: Install the `knitr` package from R,  if is not already installed.  Call the file below `<whatever>.Rnw` (note that extension is no .tex!), load it with Rstudio, and just click in the "Compile PDF" bottom. Voilà.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(head(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars1", label="tab:tbl1", scalebox="0.8"), file = 'tabl1.tex')
print(xtable(tail(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars2", label="tab:tbl2", scalebox="0.8"), file = 'tabl2.tex')
xtable(head(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars3", label="tab:tbl3", scalebox="0.8")
xtable(tail(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars4", label="tab:tbl4", scalebox="0.8")
@
\input{tabl1}
\input{tabl2}
\end{document}
```

As you will  see, the tables 1 and 2 are included form external files as you asked, although created from the same document, but the other two tables are created without print the tables in external files. Simply, the R code is replaced by the output automatically. In the background this is done by `knitr`, that export the `.Rnw` file to a true `.tex` file that finally is compiled as usual. If you are interested in this method, just search about `knitr`.

To append several outputs to the same file, you can use the `append` option of some R functions, as `sink()`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable) 
sink('tables.tex')
xtable(head(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars1", label="tab:tbl1", scalebox="0.8")
sink()

sink('tables.tex', append=TRUE)
xtable(tail(mtcars), digits =2, caption = "Mtcars2", label="tab:tbl2", scalebox="0.8")
sink()
@
\input{tables}
\end{document}
```

Although note that for use these tables in  this document, produce a extenal files is completely unnecessary.

Comment: thank you, but it seems the code saves the tabl1.tex and tabl2.tex in different .tex files. is there any way to save tabl1.tex and tabl2.tex outcomes into one single all.the.tbls.tex?

Comment: I edited the answer to add a way to do this, but using `knitr` simply you do not need to populate your working directory child files.